# How to start, pause, continue a task that executes every 5 seconds as a "keep busy" task

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I need to have some routine R which I can start and it executes a task T every 5 seconds.

Then I need to pause this repeating routine R - but ensuring that once it started a task T, this task finishes and only then the repeating routine stops starting the next task. Each started task should be allowed to finish!
The task itself takes maximum 2 seconds, so there is no overlap in the repetition!

Also I need to ensure that another routine R2 starts only after the task T has finished.

So basically this is how it should look like:

```
start R
   - R starts T the first time
   - T runs and finishes, this task T takes maximum 2 seconds
   - T starts again after 5 seconds it started the first time

now stop R (because user pressed a button)
   - let T finish
   - stop R from starting a new Task

continue with R2 (basically the task from which the button has been pressed) 
   BUT continue with R2 ONLY AFTER T has finished for sure! - and R will not repeat any new T

once R2 is done continue with R
   - so R will start a new task T
```

So basically I need the routine R with task T as some kind of a "keep busy routine" while the user reads text for example.

When the user is done reading and wants to continue by pressing on a button, the "keep busy routine" should stop and continue only again after the user's intended task has finished that was triggered by the button press in the first place

So I found

```
 private final static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
        .newScheduledThreadPool(1);

// Schedule a task to run every 5 seconds with no initial delay.
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ..do task T
        }
    }, 0L, 5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But all the stopping, continuing and the waiting for T to finish before R2 continues I do not know how to do propperly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make the problem much simpler.

- Have a recurring task which starts ever 5 seconds.
- the first thing does is check a volatile flag and if set, returns without doing anything.

To turn this process, unset the flag.  To pause it, set the flag.

You task can do more than one thing. If it needs to do an R2 after T finishes, you can check for this and execute it in the same task.  There is no need to create another task as such.

Note: if you add R2 to the same ExecutorService as T, it has to wait for it to finish before it can start R2.  This single threaded service can only do one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The ScheduledExecutorService can be stopped with the shutdown and awaitTermination methods.
Information about the methods to use with ScheduledExecutorService can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

And more information about the shutdown and await termination methods can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Shutdown seems to stop the executor from adding, accepting new tasks. The awaitTermination method lets you wait for the ending of the execution of the last task.

This should let you stop the executor and add different tasks to it.
(Avoid the the shutdownNow method.)